# How can i integrate PM2 with nodejs, nginx in windows machine

Tags: node.js, devops, pm2

I want to automate the process on app crash or server restarted.

**My environment**

- Windows machine
- Nodejs application
- nginx server

I tried the following things

I need to start my server code, client code and nginx.

Step 1: created a batch file to run all the npm related scripts

=============================

**test.bat**

```
start cmd
cd "D:\my-app"
start cmd /k "npm run start-server"
start cmd /k "npm run start-client"
cd "D:\nginx"
start cmd /k "start nginx"
```

==============================

Step 2: `npm install -g pm2`

Step 3: `pm2 start test.bat`

[image]

this throws error

[image]

If I run the **test.bat** alone. It works as expected.

Not sure why its not working on "**pm2 start test.bat**"

Anything wrong with my approach?
Any better approach? Also I want to restart all the services automatically when system restarted

Comment: Node, as far as I know, cannot run batch files. It runs Node JavaScript files.

Comment: @Tadman, thanks for your response. Is there any alternative way to run all my services ("npm run start-server", "npm run start-client" and "start nginx")

Comment: Windows has a service manager.